# Hide VBA procedures from Excel application but not from other projects

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is a long shot, but with the limitations in "Option Private Module" and even worse "Private Sub/Function", does anyone know if there is a way of hiding VBA procedures from the Excel application but not from other projects?

I have an XLAM with a subset of reusable functionality that I like to include and reference from new Excel projects, but using "Option Private Module" hinders this and if I omit it, a bunch of unusable or obscure functions and subs become visible and available to the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Convert your standard modules in the XLAM to class modules (set to
  *Public Not Creatable*);
- Create an additional Class Module that returns an instance (with a
  bit of additional work, *the instance*) of each such module; and
- Create a single standard module with one property that returns *the instance* of the main class-entry module.

**Class1:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub IAmInvisible()

End Sub
```

**ModuleEntry:**

```
Option Explicit

Private mClass As New Class1

Public Property Get TheClass() As Class1
    Set TheClass = mClass
End Property
```