# Scoped to be visible to any module but not outside the VBAProject

Tags: vba, excel

I have these function:

```
Function funcX() As Integer
    funcX = 2
End Function

Public Function funcY() As Integer
    funcY = 3
End Function
```

In a separate workbook I can run the following to access both of the above:

```
Sub xxx()

Excel.Application.Run "'myBook.xlsm'!funcX"
Excel.Application.Run "'myBook.xlsm'!funcY"

End Sub
```

How can I create a function that is scoped so it is available in all modules of its workbook but is not available outside that workbook?

Comment: THis is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713301/hide-vba-procedures-from-excel-application-but-not-from-other-projects

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Thanks. I want a `sub-routine` that is visible to all parts of its `VBAProject` but is not visible to other projects - not sure if that reference answer's my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply make the routines in a Standard Module private to the particular VBA Project, declare them as Public and add the statement:

```
Option Private Module
```

to the header of the Module.

For other considerations on controlling the visibility of VBA routines see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713301/hide-vba-procedures-from-excel-application-but-not-from-other-projects).